# Applying fixed width to body causes alignment issues

Tags: html, css

I have a html page with a tab using CSS and jQuery. Now, when I try to apply a fixed width to the body or to the main container, all the `div`s go crazy and are misaligned…  How can we give a minimum fixed width of 1200px to the body?

**Expected Output**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Faisy's</title>
    <script src="http://mihaifrentiu.com/wp-content/themes/mf/js/jquery_1.7.1.min.js"
        type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html, div, ul, li, a
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #000000;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: Comic Sans MS;
            /*min-width:800px;*/

        }

        ul
        {
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            top: 1px;
            display: table;
            border-left: 1px solid #ff0000;
        }

        ul li
        {
            float: left;
        }

        ul li a
        {
            background: #5A005A;
            color: #ffffff;
            display: block;
            padding: 6px 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-right: 1px solid white;
            border-top: 1px solid white;
            border-right: 1px solid white;
        }
        ul li a.selected
        {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
            color: #344385;
            background: #fff;
        }


        #navigation
        {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #content
        {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 500px;
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ff0000;
            z-index: 1;
            padding: 10px 0;
        }


        .clear
        {
            clear: both;
        }

        .blockDivFloatLeft
        {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }

        #banner
        {
            height: 100px;
            font-family: Comic Sans MS;
            font-size: 40px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #containerDiv
        {
            /*width:1200px;*/
        }

        #leftSub
        {
            float: left;
            width: 15%;
            min-width:250px;
            border: 3px solid white;
            height: 250px;
            margin-right:1px;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }
        #rightSub
        {
            float: left;
            width: 80%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="containerDiv">
        <div id="banner" class="blockDivFloatLeft">
            Sample
        </div>
        <div class="clear" />
        <div id="mainContent" class="blockDivFloatLeft">
            <div id="leftSub">
                <img border="0" src="/images/pulpit.jpg" alt="Photo" width="304" height="228"/>
            </div>
            <div id="rightSub">
                <div id="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="tab1" class="selected">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="tab2">My Interests</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="tab3">Talents</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="tab4">Academic</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="tab5">Achievements</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="content">out 
                    <p id="content_changer">
                        You have selected Tab 1</p>
                    <p>
                        See the page source for full code</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Tab Navigation
            $('#navigation ul a').click(function () 
            {

                //Tab Selection setting
                $('#navigation ul a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');

                //Content Setting
                $('#content_changer').html('You have selected ' + $(this).html());
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use [CSS min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) property to define the minimum width of a container..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the width that you are defining (`width: 1200px;`) is too small for the other widths that you have defined. Because you defined `#leftSub` as `min-width: 250px` and `#rightSub` as `width: 80%;` you don't have enough space for the two elements side by side so the `float: left` is not putting the two next to each other. With the widths that you have defined you need to have at least `width: 1667px` for `#containerDiv`.

You could define the body as having `min-width: 1200px;` but you will still run into problems for smaller screens because of the `min-width` on `#rightSub`.

**Note**: On top part of the CSS file, it is applied for `body, html, div, ul, li, a` all together. This can be split into multiple to avoid confusion